# Travis-CI: Knitr Not Found in loadVignetteBuilder

Tags: r, knitr, travis-ci

I've been using travis-ci successfully so far but I'm having trouble when using travis-ci with R 3.4.0 at the vignette building step with the following error in the "building package" section:

```
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... ERROR
Error in loadVignetteBuilder(vigns$pkgdir) : 
  vignette builder 'knitr' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> -> loadVignetteBuilder
Execution halted
```

When I run R-CMD-check locally it passes and I don't get any errors

Here's the current .travis.yml

```
language: R
sudo: false
install:
  - R -e "0" --args --bootstrap-packrat
cache:
  directories:
    - $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/packrat/src
    - $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/packrat/lib
  packages: true

r_packages:
    - covr

after_success:
    - Rscript -e 'library(covr); codecov()'
```

DESCRIPTION has the vignette line in it:

```
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

knitr is also in my packrat.lock file and packrat is used for the build in .travis.yml.

I've tried the following to no avail:

- added knitr to the r_packages in .travis.yml
- added knitr to the Imports in DESCRIPTION
- added `r_check_args: "--no-vignettes"` to travis.yml in the hopes of skipping the vignette building step.
- added packrat call in travis.yml from `install` to `before_install`

I'm pretty knew to building R packages, never mind travis-ci so I'm not sure if I understand why the vignette builder would not have access to the knitr package.

Repo: https://github.com/cormac85/datakindr
Travis: https://travis-ci.org/cormac85/datakindr

Comment: So in the end I got the [build to pass](https://travis-ci.org/cormac85/datakindr/builds/251766673) by just removing packrat config from the .travis.yml. This config was suggested in the [Travis R Documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#Packrat) but did not work for the loadVignetteBuilder() step during my builds.  

If anyone is still viewing this could you please comment on whether this looks like a problem specific to my build or if it's more general and worth raising an issue on the [Travis-CI Github page?](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I got the build to pass by just removing packrat config from .travis.yml and replacing it with the normal package building config: `cache: packages`.

The packrat config I used was suggested in the [Travis R Documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#Packrat) and worked well for the rest of the items in the package but it did not work for the `loadVignetteBuilder()` step during the build.

Answer (score 3):

One potential problem involves the 'Imports' and/or 'Suggests' sections in your [description file](https://github.com/cormac85/datakindr/blob/c05e65a52f8268861bdfe82680a83391fc5a404d/DESCRIPTION).

dplyr needs to be in your suggests, if not imports.

See Hadley's 2015 O'Reilly book, *[R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html)*:

> Common problems:
>
> The vignette builds interactively, but when checking, it fails with an error about a missing package that you know is installed. This means that you’ve forgotten to declare that dependency in the DESCRIPTION (usually it should go in Suggests).

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on fixing that and will remove that part from the question when done so. I had initially put it there for completeness, but I suspect it won't affect the main problem in the travis-ci build.

Comment: I think you're right, and I'm hoping that removing that noise helps provide cleaner info on the knitr message.  I'm impressed you're tackling packrat and travis on your first package.

Comment: That's very kind of you. Technically my third package, but the other two were small private projects. This one is for a charity I'm volunteering with so I thought this would be a good time to do things right including CI, docs, vignettes etc. Hence my trouble with Travis-CI and the vignette building.